# Pathfinding in 2D Arrays

Tags: java, arrays, 2d, a-star, path-finding

Let's say I have this 2D Array map

```
{ 0,0,0,0,7,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1 },
{ 0,7,7,7,7,1,1,1,24,1,1,1,1 },
{ 0,7,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,1,1,3,1 },
{ 0,7,23,23,23,23,23,23,24,1,1,3,1 },
{ 0,7,24,23,23,23,23,23,23,1,1,1,1 },
{ 0,7,24,23,23,23,23,23,23,1,1,1,1 },
{ 0,7,23,23,23,23,23,23,24,1,3,1,1 },
{ 0,7,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,1,3,1,1 },
{ 0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1 },
```

and I have HashSet full of Integers that define blocked tiles. What would be a good way so that when I click on one part of the map from where my player is standing to do a good pathfinding? A* (using nodes/etc)? What do you suggest?

Thanks.

Comment: I'd recommend, for using A*, to set the blocked tiles the `int.MaxValue` value, and forget about any hashset.

Comment: Where's a good place to learn about A*? I tried Google. :\

Comment: try wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm

Also, does the cost of moving through one tile differ from another?

Comment: @Dan _ what do the numbers in your array represent?

Comment: They define tile images in my tiles folder so tile/t1.png would be tile[1] from Image tile[]... and so and so forth.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the size of your graph is actually in the order of the example you've described, then you can safely use [Dijkstra's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra's_algorithm), given that it's somewhat simpler to implement than A*, and there is no real need for heuristic algorithms if you can do an exhaustive search in almost the same time :)

As for your comment about "using nodes/etc", this already is a graph, albeit a slightly akward representation of one.  Every array value is a node, and "edges" are given by adjacency in the array.  The blocked tiles can either be done by inhibiting adjacency (i.e. look up the list of blocked tiles to determine whether another node is reachable from the current one under consideration), or as Yossarian suggested above, just set the cost of that tile to something so large as to be practically infinite.  However, if you take the latter approach, you'll want to ensure that those tiles never inadvertently end up in a solution!

Comment: You know what? This seems a bit advanced for me. I'll go learn the basics of Java Game AI & Logic. I've got the books "Developing Games in Java" by David Brackeen and "Beginning Java Game Programming Second Edition" by Jonathan S. Harbour and "Killer Game Programming in Java" by Andrew Davison. I'll get back to you when I read up on those. Huzzah!

Comment: @Dan - This is a very good answer and you should really consider it. If you are scared of graphs just use a graph library like jgraph which already has a Djikstra shortest path function

Comment: I'll take a look into jgraph. Care to linking me to it's website? Can't find it on Google because it's just a common word.

Comment: @Dan, if you are slightly confused about the representations of graphs, perhaps Adjacency matrices are a good place to start reading. If you reformulated your array in this way, the problem might suddenly become a lot simpler.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix